# Convert HTML files to PDF

Tags: ruby, pdfkit

I am trying to convert a html file to pdf using the ruby gem pdfkit. I can create a pdf file, but the links in the pdf file don't work.Can someone please tell me if there is any other tool to convert html files to pdf or can we fix the links using pdfkit?

Comment: What do you mean "the links [...] don't work"?  They don't appear has hyperlinks in the PDF?  Is it for all links or just relative ones?

Comment: It appears as hyperlinks, but doesn't redirect to the specified place.Some links do work,the ones that redirected to in the same file do not work

Answer (score 0):

Check [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) library, have been using for a long time... never faced any issue.